# C# - Duplicate Altering

Tags: c#, string, split, duplicates

I have a file that looks like this:

```
R.D.    P.N.      X       Y        Rot  Pkg
L5      120910    64.770  98.425   180  SOP8                    
P4      120911   -69.850  98.425   180  SOIC12                    
L10     120911   -19.685  83.820   180  SOIC10                    
P4      120911    25.400  83.820   180  0603                    
L5      120910    62.484  98.425   180  SOP8
L5      120910    99.100  150.105  180  SOP8
..      ......    ......  ......   ..   .......
```

I would like to use `string.Split()` to split each string up and then check the first value of the "string[0]" on every line. If there are duplicates of the same string[0] I would like to add an incremented "-#" to the end of the string[0]. So it would be something like `string[0] + "-i"`.....

What I mean by this is that for the `L5`'s in the .txt above, they would be changed to `L5-1`,`L5-2`,`L5-3`. The same goes with the `P4`'s (ie, `P4-1`,`P4-2`)....

---

So the new .txt would look like this:

```
R.D.      P.N.      X       Y        Rot  Pkg
L5-1      120910    64.770  98.425   180  SOP8                    
P4-1      120911   -69.850  98.425   180  SOIC12                    
L10       120911   -19.685  83.820   180  SOIC10                    
P4-2      120911    25.400  83.820   180  0603                    
L5-2      120910    62.484  98.425   180  SOP8
L5-3      120910    99.100  150.105  180  SOP8
..      ......    ......  ......   ..   .......
```

---

***QUESTIONS:***

- How can I go about doing such a thing?
- Any help on understand how to do this?

Comment: How large is this file? And are you willing to not append a number to the first occurrence of a name? So it would be L5, L5-1, L5-2, etc.

Comment: @Mannimarco: The file length is not set as it can be any length (but will probably never exceed over 800 lines or so)... I would definitely prefer all occurences to append the number, so including the first value.. (L5-1, L5-2, L5-3)

Comment: @Colton: That makes it so you need to scan the file twice, or have to store the values somewhere temporarily. The reason is that you won't know to put a -1 on something until you hit a duplicate value (at which point you've already passed the original). It complicates things more.

Comment: How important is memory? If this can be stored in memory and modified before writing out he values it would make things easier.

Comment: Then would you be okay with adding a -1 even if there isn't a second occurrence? This will seriously make your life easier. Like Jason Down said, you'd need to know about the entire file before writing anything if you really wanted to avoid this.. and that can get ugly.

Comment: @Jason: Hmm I understand it makes it more complicated.. :(. Memory is not too important.

Comment: @Mannimarco: Yes I would be fine with adding a "-1" even if there is not a second occurence :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are ok with having a -1 for all values that only contain one occurrence, here is a samples program. You'd have to do a copy at the end, since you can't delete the original file while writing the new one.

```
// Replace c:\temp\temp.txt with you original file.
// Replace c:\temp\temp2.txt with your temporary new file.

using (var r = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\temp.txt"))
{
    using (var w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\temp2.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        var counter = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        // write header first, no changes necessary
        if ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            w.WriteLine(line);
        }

        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            // assuming it is safe to split on a space
            var values = line.Split(' ');

            // if the value hasn't been encountered before, add it
            if (!counter.ContainsKey(values[0]))
            {
                // start counter at 0
                counter.Add(values[0], 0);
            }

            // increment the count as we hit each occurrence of the
            // given key
            counter[values[0]] = counter[values[0]] + 1;

            // write out the original line, replacing the key with the
            // format key-#
            w.WriteLine(line.Replace(values[0], 
                                     string.Format("{0}-{1}", 
                                                   values[0], 
                                                   counter[values[0]])));
        }
    }
}
```

Sample input:

```
R.D.    P.N.      X       Y        Rot  Pkg
L5      120910    64.770  98.425   180  SOP8                    
P4      120911   -69.850  98.425   180  SOIC12                    
L10     120911   -19.685  83.820   180  SOIC10                    
P4      120911    25.400  83.820   180  0603                    
L5      120910    62.484  98.425   180  SOP8
L5      120910    99.100  150.105  180  SOP8
```

Sample output (tested):

```
R.D.    P.N.      X       Y        Rot  Pkg
L5-1    120910    64.770  98.425   180  SOP8                    
P4-1    120911   -69.850  98.425   180  SOIC12                    
L10-1   120911   -19.685  83.820   180  SOIC10                    
P4-2    120911    25.400  83.820   180  0603                    
L5-2    120910    62.484  98.425   180  SOP8
L5-3    120910    99.100  150.105  180  SOP8
```

If you don't want the -1, you can always do a check before the write to ensure that the count is > 1.

Comment: NOTE: You'd have to tweak the write slightly, as it will actually shift each value to the right (as in L5 changed to L5-1 would mean everything on that line from that point on would be shifted two spaces to the right).

Comment: I had a couple minutes to burn, thought I'd give 'er a whirl.

Answer (score 2):

How I would do it:

1. Open file to read, open another file to write to.
2. Read header from original file, write to new file.
3. Create empty string to int dictionary.
4. Begin loop:
5. Read line, split out name.
6. If the name doesn't exist in the dictionary, add it to the dictionary as a key with an integer value of 1.
7. Append the name + dictionary value for the given name (eg, name is "L5", integer is 3, so append "L5-3") and the rest of the contents of the line (saved from step 5) to the new file.
8. Increment dictionary value for given name.
9. Repeat from step 4.
10. Delete old file, change new file name to match previous file.

Edit for dictionary example:

```
//Create an empty dictionary
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

//Add a key/value pair
dictionary.Add("L5", 1);

//Check if the value exists, if not then add it
if( !dictionary.ContainsKey("L9") )
    dictionary.Add("L9", 1);

//Get the value (after making sure the value exists)
int value = dictionary["L5"];

//Increment the value
dictionary["L5"] = value + 1;
```

You should only use the `dictionary[string]` syntax if you know the dictionary already includes that key, otherwise you risk getting an error. Another way to do it is to use the TryGetValue method:

```
int value;
if( dictionary.TryGetValue("L5", out value) )
{
    //Key exists already
    Console.WriteLine("L5 has a value of {0}", value);
}
else
{
    //Key does not exist
    dictionary.Add("L5", 1);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with a dictionary. Is there anyway you could show psudo-code/code?

Comment: @Colton Added an example of everything I think you'll need concerning the dictionary. They're really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks! Got a question..so for the `dictionary.Add("L5", 1);` would I change that to something like: `dictionary.Add(splitValue[0], i);`? Assuming that the splitValue[] is the first value that was split on the line, and that i is an incrementing...?

Comment: You'd need to do `dictionary.Add(splitValue[0], 1);` then increment the value using `int val = dictionary[splitValue[0]]; dictionary[splitValue[0]] = val + 1` when you find another occurrence of the same name.

Comment: Jason Down's program looks like it should work perfectly if you want to just copy that.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
 string[] input = {"R.D.    P.N.      X       Y        Rot  Pkg",
"L5 120910    64.770  98.425   180  SOP8",
"P4      120911   -69.850  98.425   180  SOIC12",
"L10     120911   -19.685  83.820   180  SOIC10",
"P4      120911    25.400  83.820   180  0603",
"L5      120910    62.484  98.425   180  SOP8",
"L5      120910    99.100  150.105  180  SOP8"};

    var control = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    var result = new List<string[]>();

    foreach (var line in input)
    {
       var array = line.Split(' ');
       result.Add(array);
       int occurencies = 0;
       ;
       control[array[0]] = control.TryGetValue(array[0], out occurencies) 
                           ? occurencies == 1 ? -2 : occurencies - 1
                           : 1;
    }

    foreach (var item in result.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
    {
       int value = control[item[0]];
       if (value < 0)
       {
          control[item[0]] = value + 1;
          item[0] = item[0] + value;     
       }
    }
```

This will give you the result you are after. There may be more efficient ways, but, for 800 lines this should be good enough.

Comment: How would I go about it if I did not know the string values you have hard coded into the `string[] input = {...}`?

Comment: You just have to use a stream to read the file from disk and as you read split the lines and so on. The change is very simple, basically you have to obtain a stream that can read from the file system and the first foreach is replaced by a While(..ReadLine...).

Answer (score 0):

800 lines is pretty tiny.

1. Go through the array, and add the first column to a dictionary.  Before adding to the dictionary test to see if the value apperas in it.  If it does, just increment the counter.
2. Go through your dictionary.  For each key whose value is greater than 1, cycle the array and append "-1", "-2", etc to all occurrences of the key.  ..

Not very efficient, but pretty easy to implement